# How I can automate creating transfer groups on Stripe?

Tags: stripe-payments

I found "separate charges and transfer" is the best payment flow for my apps. But I want to make the process of creating these groups automatic, is it possible? if not is there a way to implement the same logic in stripe?

Comment: You can provide any string you like for the `transfer_group` field, and then track it on your own systems to know when to reuse those fields or programmatically generate a new one.

Comment: @taintedzodiac Hello, Thanks for your help, Can you please provide more details? I didn't get the point excatly.

Comment: Which part are you wondering about, more specifically? You can generate the values of the group strings any way you prefer, e.g. a random string if desired, or concatenating date with something meaningful, etc.

Comment: I think you didn't get my question, I'm asking if there is a way to make this creating process automated! such as using Zapier! Or is there a way to use a user interface for that instead of coding? Thanks.